# w2812b led strip flashing except when touching data line

Tags: pi-zero, led

I'm working on a led script with a w2812b strip and a pizero. I have a cap on between the data and ground and a resistor on the data line. When I run the script the strip flashes seemingly randomly, except when I touch the downstream leg of the resistor on the data line, the flashing stops and the code seems to be working as it should. It doesn't seem to matter whether the code is powering one led or all of them, or if i have an external power source for the led or not, it acts the same. Does anyone have any solutions? Thank you!

```
import board
from rpi_ws281x import Adafruit_NeoPixel, Color
import neopixel
import digitalio
import time

# Pin assignments
pixel_pin = board.D10
num_pixels = 25  # Number of LEDs in strip
button_left = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D3)
button_right = digitalio.DigitalInOut(board.D5)
button_left.switch_to_input(pull=digitalio.Pull.UP)
button_right.switch_to_input(pull=digitalio.Pull.UP)

# Create NeoPixel object
#pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(pixel_pin, num_pixels, brightness=0.1, auto_write=False)
pixels = neopixel.NeoPixel(pixel_pin, num_pixels, brightness=0.1, auto_write=True)

# Initial player position
player_pos = 0

def move_pixel(direction):
  global player_pos
  player_pos = (player_pos + direction) % num_pixels  # Wrap around at the ends
  pixels.fill((0, 0, 0))  # Clear strip
  pixels[player_pos] = (255, 255, 255)  # Set player pixel
  pixels.show()

def apply_physics():
  global player_pos
  velocity = 10  # Adjust for desired sliding speed
  if player_pos > 0 and pixels[player_pos - 1] == (0, 0, 0):
    player_pos -= velocity
  if player_pos < num_pixels - 1 and pixels[player_pos + 1] == (0, 0, 0):
    player_pos += velocity

while True:
  if not button_left.value:
    move_pixel(-1)  # Move left
    time.sleep(0.03)  # Delay for smoother movement
  elif not button_right.value:
    move_pixel(1)  # Move right
    time.sleep(0.03)
    time.sleep(1)
  else:
    apply_physics()  # Apply sliding physics
  pixels.show()
```

Comment: `a cap` and `a resistor` ... these components have values, perhaps it is important to know what they are

Comment: Apologies, the cap is a 680uf 16v and the resistor is a 470 ohm 1/4 watt.

Comment: and how are you connecting the light strip - also `resistor on the data line` in what sense? a resistor has two ends, you seem to have described one, unless it's inline? and if it is inline, why? I've never used a resistor on the data line of an addressable LED strip (hmmm, seems it's a thing some guides doi though)

Comment: Currently its connected to the pi's 5v gpio pin, and grounded on the pi as well. The resistor is inline on the data line, but it doesn't seem to make a difference whether it's on there or not.

Comment: what about the capacitor? why is that there?

Comment: It was recommended here  [link](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-neopixel-uberguide/the-magic-of-neopixels)

Comment: no mention of a capacitor from data to ground in that link.

Comment: 8 links away from the link you provided (why didn't you just link to that page??? seriously) ... *"on LARGER projects you MAY need to add a capacitor across the + and - terminals"* ... no mention of a capacitor from data to ground, and anyway, 25 pixels is a SMALL project

Comment: Also, a pi is a 3.3v device, so you should be using a level shifter - that's on the 9th page after your link

Comment: Apologies about the errors in my description. I'll give the level shifter a try, thank you for your help.

Comment: I'd remove the capacitor first

Comment: A 680uF cap between data and ground (if that is what you're using here) is definitely not a good idea, as it will attenuate the (high frequency) output signal from the RPi GPIO and the WS2812 data pin. This is not what the Adafruit link is recommending. A cap between V+ and GND is a much better idea as it will stabilize the supply going into the LED string. My experience with WS2812 is that it will work with a 3.3 V input, so a level shifter might not be absolutely necessary (but would be recommended only if this is not a one-off).

Comment: To clarify from above, I do have the cap between the V+ and ground on the strip. I have another project that only updates every two minutes with static lights and it works fine with 3.3V. I'll still give the level shifter a go and see if it resolves my issues. Thanks for the help.